# The choice between "A" or "The"

Tags: descriptive-grammar

This month is the 50th anniversary of Ronald Reagan's "The Speech". The title of his speech is however "A Time For Choosing". Why is it not "The Time For Choosing"?

Comment: Because that's what he wrote.

Comment: Because it is one of many, and not the only one ever.